# Haskell: Converting between typeclasses

Tags: haskell

For this data:

```
data A = A
data B = B

class C1 a where repr :: a -> String
instance C1 A where repr _ = "A"
instance C1 B where repr _ = "B"

class C2 a
instance C2 A
```

Is there a way to implement function with this type?

```
conv :: (C1 a, C2 b) => a -> Maybe b
```

It should return `Just . id` for argument of type that is an instance of `C2`, and `Nothing` for any other type.

`repr` is injective. I can change class `C2` but class `C1` is in external library.

Comment: Please be more concrete. Don't oversimplify the problem. As it currently stands, this question seems to be an instance of the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: I don't see any oversimplification. Example is pretty concrete and question is basically yes/no. If it's not possible to do what I need, please answer that it is not, and I'll be thankful if you will explain why.

Comment: The problem with your question is that you are asking about your __attempted solution__ instead of your __actual problem__. You have a problem for which you want a solution, and you have already thought of a solution (in your case implementing the `conv` function). Hence, you're asking if the `conv` function can be implemented. However, instead if you tell us your actual problem (the one you're trying to solve by implementing the `conv` function) then we can give you a better answer. Hence, it's an oversimplification of the __actual__ problem that you have. Just trying to help here for free.

Comment: This is very unclear to me as well.

Comment: Sorry, I don't mean to dismiss your help, I appreciate it very much. It's just that I see several solutions to my current task, and one of them requires converting between typeclasses. And I don't know if this is actually possible at all. I don't want to spend time explaining the general problem, when I just need to know the answer to this specific yes/no question...

Comment: IIRC, Haskell is designed so that adding instances never changes the behaviour of already-working code. In particular, that means that adding `instance C2 B` never changes the result of `show (conv B)`

Comment: @immibis, overlapping and incoherent instance extensions can break that rule by the power of being nasty. But it's generally best to avoid such things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this is not possible. The open-world assumption says that there is no way to show (either at compile time or at runtime) that a given type is *not* an instance of a given class.

Comment: Good answer. But it raises another question: what if we know the types that belong to `C2` exactly? We can match `repr` results with those types, but is it possible at all to return `a -> Maybe a`... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36033698/haskell-filtering-by-type

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need the `C2` type class at all? You could simply do this:

```hs
conv :: C1 a => a -> Maybe a
conv a = case repr a of
             "A" -> Just a
             _   -> Nothing
```

This works under the assumption that the `repr` function is [injective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function).

---

**Edit:** Here's how to implement the `conv` function the way you want:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

conv :: (C1 a, C2 b, a ~ b) => a -> Maybe b
conv a = case repr a of
             "A" -> Just a
             _   -> Nothing
```

Note that the equality constraint `a ~ b` is required. It tells the compiler that type `a` and type `b` must be the same type. To use the equality constraint we need to enable the `TypeFamilies` extension.

Comment: There are many instances of `C2` (hundreds) and `C2` class actually has several methods. Using this solution (without class at all), we would have to create several different big functions similar to `conv`, each will basically list all names of types that would be `C2` instances. Also, we want to ensure, that for each type which is an instance of `C2` all methods are implemented. Again, that would be difficult using separate functions...

Comment: Why would you need to create several functions similar to `conv`? Just one will do, granted that it will be a pretty big function if you have hundreds of instances of `C2`.

Comment: Ensuring that all the methods of an instance of a type class are implemented is the job of the compiler. Your question is terribly oversimplified. I don't know what you're trying to do. Please be more concrete. This seems to be an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Let's say for example, that `C2` has methods `push :: a -> IO ()` and `pull :: a -> IO ()`. If I'll get rid of `C2`, I'll have to create functions `push :: C1 a => a -> IO ()` and `pull :: C1 a => a -> IO ()`. Each of them will have `case` with list of all possible C1 instances that can push and pull. And compiller won't help to ensure that I have added one to `push`  but forgot to add it to `pull`. No oversimplification here. My question is about converting between partially intersecting typeclasses.

Comment: I updated my answer showing how to implement the `conv` function the way you want. However, note that you'll still need a really big `case` expression.

Comment: There are also overlapping instances and the type family workarounds for those.

Comment: @dfeuer, can you please answer with example?

Comment: I tried to compile solution (in update), and I get `No instance for (C2 B) arising from a use of ‘conv’`. Here is what I compiled: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5005589990f7e3a25017

Comment: @SergeyMitskevich, you want me to spend 30+ minutes constructing and explaining an example of a technique that may or may not be remotely appropriate for your application? I doubt that's the best use of my time. Could you explain your underlying problem properly please?

Comment: @dfeuer, sorry, I thought you meant there is a solution to this particular question that uses overlapping instances...

Comment: @SergeyMitskevich That's because type class `C2` has no instance for data type `B`. Hence, you can't apply the `conv` function to the value `B`. It's a compile time error instead of the runtime `Nothing` value you expect. By adding the `a ~ b` constraint I've made the type stronger. What you want to do is make the type weaker, which is in fact very difficult to do. Hence, I'm asking for the actual problem.

Comment: @SergeyMitskevich, I gave a brief example in https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2016-February/123205.html and you can also try to dig them up on the Haskell wiki somewhere.

Comment: dfeuer, thanks, I'll look into that. AaditMShah, yes my whole question is about changing the constraint. Is it possible or not, in the particular model that I have described in the question. Without any assumptions about any other problems, please.